Как значения из словаря подставить в InlineKeyboardButton в aiogram?
key_id = data.get_charter() # Получаю словарь

char1 = list(key_id.values())[0] # Получаю значения              
char2 = list(key_id.values())[1] # из словаря по номеру                
char3 = list(key_id.values())[2] # ключа
char4 = list(key_id.values())[3]
char5 = list(key_id.values())[4]
char6 = list(key_id.values())[5]
char7 = list(key_id.values())[6]
char8 = list(key_id.values())[7]

Затем надо эти 8 значений вбить в текст кнопки InlineKeyboardButton(text=""), чтобы получилось 8 кнопок.
ред.:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, MagicFilter, Router
from aiogram import F
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart, Command
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
from aiogram.types import FSInputFile, URLInputFile, BufferedInputFile, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, KeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import ReplyKeyboardBuilder, InlineKeyboardBuilder
from datetime import datetime
from aiogram.fsm.state import StatesGroup, State
from aiogram.fsm.context import FSMContext
from aiogram.filters import StateFilter
from aiogram.enums import ChatAction
from starrailcard.src.api import enka
from starrailcard.src.showcase import error
from starrailcard.src.api.error import StarRailCardError
import asyncio
import logging
import starrailcard
import starrailcard.src.showcase.error
import enka
from text import get_some_kb

from settings import tok

TYPING = "typing"
        
  

class Reg(StatesGroup):
    name = State()
    name1 = State()


router = Router()

@router.message(Command('character'),
                 StateFilter(None)
)
async def enkanet(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.set_state(Reg.name)
    await message.answer('Напиши свой ID')
    print("card request")
    

    
@router.message(
        StateFilter(Reg.name)
)
async def character_card(message: Message,
                           state: FSMContext,
) -> None:  # noqa: C901, D103        
    await state.update_data(name=message.text)
    await state.set_state(None)
    data = await state.get_data()
    await message.bot.send_chat_action(
        chat_id=message.chat.id,
        action=ChatAction.TYPING
    )
    await message.answer("ЖДИ\n\n\nСекунд 15~20")
    async with starrailcard.Card(save=True, remove_logo=True) as card: #Модуль генерации картинки
        try:
            await card.set_lang("ru") #Из модуля
            data = await card.create(data["name"], style=2, force_update=True) #Из модуля
            key_id = data.get_charter() #Из модуля
            get_some_kb(key_id)
            await message.answer("", reply_markup=kb)                                                   
        except enka.errors.PlayerDoesNotExistError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("АШЫПКА")
        except KeyError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("АШЫПКА")
        except enka.errors.GameMaintenanceError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("АШЫПКА")
        except ValueError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("Введите свой ID ЦИФРАМИ")     
        except StarRailCardError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("АШЫПКА")        
        except starrailcard.src.showcase.error.ApiError:
            print("card is not ok")
            return message.answer("АШЫПКА")

        





  
async def main():  
    bot = Bot(token=tok)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.include_router(router)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
  try:
      asyncio.run(main())
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
      print('exit') 

key_id = data.get_charter()
data228 = get_some_kb(key_id)
print(data228) #Принт в терминал выдает 
   # По идее всё должно нормально работать, если подставить data228 в markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(data228)

inline_keyboard=[[InlineKeyboardButton(text='������', url=None, callback_data='call_1308', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None), InlineKeyboardButton(text='����� � ��������', url=None, callback_data='call_1112', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None)], [InlineKeyboardButton(text='�������', url=None, callback_data='call_1309', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None), InlineKeyboardButton(text='�����', url=None, callback_data='call_1005', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None)], [InlineKeyboardButton(text='�����', url=None, callback_data='call_1205', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None), InlineKeyboardButton(text='���������� ����', url=None, callback_data='call_1006', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None)], [InlineKeyboardButton(text='׸���� ������', url=None, callback_data='call_1307', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None), InlineKeyboardButton(text='�������', url=None, callback_data='call_1306', web_app=None, login_url=None, switch_inline_query=None, switch_inline_query_current_chat=None, switch_inline_query_chosen_chat=None, callback_game=None, pay=None)]]


Вам же в вашем другом вопросе уже ответили

Не, мне надо в кнопки поместить текст значений. У меня все работает до момента подставления в кнопки

Должно получиться markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(inline_keyboard=[InlineKeyboardButton(text=f'{char1}', callback_data='character1') и так для 8-ми кнопок

В функцию мы передаем ваш словарь, дальше проходимся циклом по словарю и в билдер клавиатуры добавляем кнопки. Метод adjust устанавливает ширину строки клавиатуры, метод as_markup возвращает объект клавиатуры.
from aiogram.types import InlineKeyboardMarkup
from aiogram.utils.keyboard import InlineKeyboardBuilder


def get_some_kb(some_dict: dict) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    kb = InlineKeyboardBuilder()
    for key, value in some_dict.items():
        kb.button(text=value, callback_data=f"call_{key}")
    kb.adjust(2)
    return kb.as_markup()

Настоятельный совет, выучите питон прежде, чем писать ботов. Если вы плохо понимаете как реализовать вашу задачу в циклах и как работают словари, то в ботов явно рано.

Вот так должно получиться ?
key_id = data.get_charter()  get_some_kb(key_id)  return message.answer("", reply_markup=kb) (Тут в комментариях переносы не работают, в коде всё как надо стоит)

@Torrtozzo да, все верно

ValueError , kb не распознается NameError

@Torrtozzo покажите весь ваш код, можете отредактировать свой первоначальный вопрос

Отредактировал свой вопрос, добавив код

Ваш код работает, если что. Как я понял мне надо было сделать data228 = get_some_kb(key_id) markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(InlineKeyboardButton(data228)) data228 содержит в себе inline_keyboard=

Я разобрался ! Спасибо за код, я его сохраню. key_id = data.get_charter() kb = get_some_kb(key_id) await message.answer("Выберите персонажа", reply_markup=kb) Итоговый вариант, который работает

@Torrtozzo примите тогда ответ как правильный
